# Why my format verb in the fmt.Println doesn't interporate my data?

Tags: go

I'm confusing why my format verb doesn't work?

My code is as follow:

```
fmt.Println("Add %v to cache.", label.ExternalID)
```

At this time, the variable **label.ExternalID** has nDNYgvjz.
so, I'm expecting some result like **Add nDNYgvjz to cache.**
But, I've got the following result:

```
Add %v to cache. nDNYgvjz
```

What's happen? Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: You have to use `fmt.Printf()` not `fmt.Println()`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Println without formatting verb: fmt.Println("Add ", label.ExternalID, "to cache."). In your case it’s equivalent because you use the %v verb which is the default formatting option for any type of variable.

Answer (score 1):

Println does not format the string. You should use Printf (which will format the string) and add a new line at the end to copy the function of Println (add a new line at end).

instead of

```
fmt.Println("Add %v to cache.", label.ExternalID)
```

you should use

```
fmt.Printf("Add %v to cache. \n", label.ExternalID)
```